# Map, filter and fork in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

> Here are some equations; at least one of them is false. Which are the true ones, and which are false?
>
> ```
> map f . take n    = take n . map f
> map f . reverse   = reverse . map f
> map f . sort      = sort . map f
> map f . filter p  = map fst . filter snd . map (fork (f,p))
> reverse . concat  = concat . reverse . map reverse
> filter p . concat = concat . map (filter p)
> ```
>
> Justify your answer for each with an example.

Its a question I got in my assignment. I checked all the equations but all the equations are coming true. I can't find any test case in which any equation is false. Please help me find the equation which is false

Comment: You might want to broaden your choices for your `f` test function. Did you try something like the sine function for example ?

Comment: Some list functions like `reverse` operate on lists of arbitrary types. Others don't, like `sum` that operates only on lists of numbers. The latter case is suspicious, and indeed it would break equations like `f . sum = sum . map f`. Try seeing if there are similarly suspicious functions in your homework text.

Comment: What does "checked" mean in this context? You're supposed to decide, for example, if `map f . sort = sort . map f` is true for *all* functions `f`, not just find a function `f` for which it is true. (Either it's true for all `f`, or you can find an `f` for which it is *not* true.)

Comment: One of your 6 equations can be expressed in plain English by a sentence like: “Function `f` has the xyz property”. Once you have figured out which of the 6 equations that is, you just need to find *one* function `f` that does **not** have the xyz property.

Comment: @chepner I thought of all the possible inputs for the functions which I could think of. If you find any input on which these functions do not hold please let me know.

Comment: That's your job. But I will say, there are trivial functions for which `map f . sort = sort . map f` does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the third equation:

```
map f . sort  =  sort . map f
```

In plain English, it means that going thru function `f` can be done equivalently before or after sorting the input list. Hence, function f is *order preserving*, or equivalently: *increasing*.

So let's peak a function that is **not** increasing. For example library function `negate` which multiplies its input by minus one.

**Testing:**

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.List (sort)
 λ> 
 λ> negate 4
 -4
 λ> 
 λ> negate (-3)
 3
 λ> 
 λ> (map negate . sort) [1,2,3]
 [-1,-2,-3]
 λ> 
 λ> (sort . map negate) [1,2,3]
 [-3,-2,-1]
 λ> 
 λ> (sort . map negate) [1,2,3] == (map negate . sort) [1,2,3] 
 False
 λ>
```

So we have found our counter-example, as required by the rules of the game.